# SQL conditional data display based on multiple tables and columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to display several columns of `tableX` data when the value of a specific column matches that of the corresponding column in `tableY`.

Imagine we have 2 tables: one named `person` containing a column named `membershipid` and the other named `tasks`containing a column named `memberid`. In this case, the condition for display a record would be the following:

`membershipid` on `person` = `memberid` on `tasks`

Does this require the use of a JOIN clause or can I still use the WHERE keyword for this?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using Postgres for this setup.

Comment: @speshock Did any of the answers below help to answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've understood of your question, it sounds like yes you'll need an `INNER JOIN` to pull out only the rows from `tableX` where there is a matching value in the joined column in `tableY`.

So something like:

```
SELECT tableXcol1, tableXcol2, tableXcol3
FROM tableX
INNER JOIN tableY
ON tableX.specific_column = tableY.specific_column
```

Answer (score 1):

ALthough it can be done with `where` clauses, I would recommend you to use joins.

**The `where` style (not recommended)**

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2, ...
from aTable as t1, anotherTable as t2
where t1.field1 = t2.field1;
```

**The `join`style (recommended)**

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2, ...
from aTable as t1 inner join anotherTable as t2 on t1.field1 = t2.field1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need data from tableX but not from tableY, doing a `JOIN` would likely give you duplicate data. Use `EXISTS` instead, e.g.

```
SELECT person.col1, person.col2
FROM person
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tasks
        WHERE
            person.membershipid = tasks.memberid
    )
```